# No "Default" option for Google Wallet Balance in Google Wallet app

Tags: applications, google

My mother-in-law has an iPhone 5c and is using the latest version of the Google Wallet app. I'm trying to set the Google Wallet Balance as her default payment method so money sent to her doesn't go directly into one of the bank accounts she has set up. On *my* phone, which is a 6s+ with latest version of the app, I have an option to make it the default, but my mother-in-law doesn't have that option in hers. What gives?

See below for a screenshot of her app. On mine, under Google Wallet Balance, I have that same ‘default’ dropdown that's visible in the screenshot under the bank account.

[image: Google Wallet app with no default option for Google Wallet Balance]

Comment: Perhaps because the Apple 5c does not have NFC (for Apple Pay & the like,) Google Wallet does not do what you are hoping to do. https://www.howtogeek.com/212290/how-to-set-up-apple-pay-and-google-wallet-on-your-phone/

Comment: Good thought, but this feature doesn't have anything to do with NFC. Making the Google Wallet Balance the default option simply sets where money goes by default when it's sent to you electronically.